# Custom Library Pin Change

Tags: pins, library

I'm using an Arduino Uno with Funduino I2C 1602 LCD display. The LCD display is connected as

LCD

SCL--> A5
SDA -->A4

I need to measure the temperature, pressure and the velocity of a duct flow. So I connected a BMP180 to my arduino with the following connection

SCL--> A5
SDA -->A4

As you can see, both of them are connected to same pins. The connection works fine just for BMP180 but when I add a rotary encoder and print its value on LCD, I'm getting delayed and wrong data.

I'm using this BMP180 library 
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP085_Unified

The LCD uses this library (v1.2.0)

https://bitbucket.org/fmalpartida/new-liquidcrystal/downloads

how can I change bmp180 or LCD analog pins in these libraries?

Comment: You can have multiple devices connected to the same I2C pin (A4,A5). So both devices worked till you connected the rotary encoder? What pins are the encoder connected to?

Comment: actually, I think I'm having a coding problem. Encoder is connected to digital pins so there is no problem with it.